# Which command produces a webdriver log like this?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Which command produces a webdriver log like this?

```
System info: host: 'SOMEHOST', ip: '1.1.1.1', os.name: 'Windows 8', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '8.0', java.version: '1.8.0_361'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, browserVersion: 117.0.1, javascriptEnabled: true, moz:accessibilityChecks: false, moz:buildID: 20230912013654, moz:geckodriverVersion: 0.33.0, moz:headless: true, moz:platformVersion: 10.0, moz:processID: 1772, moz:profile: C:\Users\36B5~1\AppData\Loc..., moz:shutdownTimeout: 60000, moz:webdriverClick: true, moz:windowless: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: 137d5151-92d1-31af-970b-3a1db9d113b9
```

Comment: Well, which command did you run?

Comment: @knittl `try {server.run(driver);} catch (Exception e) { logger.warning("error in main block: ".concat(e.getMessage())); captureScreenshot(driver, String.format("%s\\screenshots", System.getProperty("user.home"))); logger.info("screenshot saved");} finally { ...` somehere before finally but right after `logger.warning`

Comment: So `server.run(driver)` (somewhere down the call stack) prints the message. Am I underthinking this question? If you remove that line, the message will not be printed; so this line is responsible for printing it. No? If not, what _exactly_ is the question here?